# Mysql join two tables where clause

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

So I'm listing some activities based on a form where the user select the country, date, etc..
There's two tables, the main one "actividades" is where I have the name, price, number of participants, etc and then I have "tarifas" where I put special rules for activities, for example if on a specific day that activity is available or not. there could be a rule or not, if there's not any rule, I want to list that activity, if there's a rule, I only want to list it if that day is availabe which is what tarifas.fechado = 0 is supposed to do.

Everything else is working, can someone help me sort this out?

```
if (!$sql = $db->sql_query("SELECT actividades.dias, actividades.id_pais, actividades.id_regiao, actividades.nome, actividades.id_empresa, actividades.id, actividades.dias, actividades.preco, actividades.id_subcategoria, actividades.hora 
                            FROM actividades 
                            LEFT JOIN tarifas ON actividades.id = tarifas.id_actividade 
                                              AND tarifas.dia = '$dia' 
                                              AND tarifas.fechado = 0 
                            WHERE pais = '$pais' 
                            AND actividades.dias LIKE '%$diaExtenso%' 
                            ORDER BY actividades.id ASC 
                            LIMIT $pageLimit, $porpagina")) 
       {message_die("DS", TRUE); }
```

Comment: did you check the output of the query? Not the result but what the actual query looks like.

Comment: SELECT actividades.dias, actividades.id_pais, actividades.id_regiao, actividades.nome, actividades.id_empresa, actividades.id, actividades.dias, actividades.preco, actividades.id_subcategoria, actividades.hora FROM actividades LEFT JOIN tarifas ON actividades.id = tarifas.id_actividade AND tarifas.dia = '2014-12-10' AND tarifas.fechado = 0 WHERE actividades.id_pais = '1' AND actividades.id_regiao = '5' AND actividades.dias LIKE '%Quarta%' ORDER BY actividades.id ASC LIMIT 0, 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some of your join conditions need to be in the `WHERE` clause instead.  I'm not clear on how `tarifas.dia` fits into the picture, but this query will return all `actividades` rows that have no related `tarifas` row, plus all those that do have a `tarifas` row for which `tarifas.dia` has the specified value and `tarifas.fechado` is zero.  (I have formatted it for readability):

```
SELECT
  actividades.dias,
  actividades.id_pais,
  actividades.id_regiao,
  actividades.nome,
  actividades.id_empresa,
  actividades.id,
  actividades.dias,
  actividades.preco,
  actividades.id_subcategoria,
  actividades.hora
FROM
  actividades
  LEFT JOIN tarifas
    ON actividades.id = tarifas.id_actividade
WHERE
  pais = '$pais'
  AND actividades.dias LIKE '%$diaExtenso%'
  AND (tarifas.id_actividade IS NULL
    OR (tarifas.dia = '$dia' AND tarifas.fechado = 0))
ORDER BY actividades.id ASC
LIMIT $pageLimit, $porpagina
```

It is possible that you want to move the condition on `tarifas.dia` back into the join predicate.  Doing so would cause `tarifas` rows to be ignored unless they have the specified `dia` value.